# Example with multi-hidden layers of perceptron backpropagation

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation, perceptron

i'm looking for an example of a multi-layer perceptron where a learning pass is done, backpropagation, using sigmoid. To have at least 2 hidden layers, so that I can check the outputs of my own code against that, let's call it, a rosetta stone.

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you use tensorflow, pytorch or something standard as rosetta stone?

Comment: Do  you mean "classic" Rosenblatt's Perceptron? SGD-free, with perceptron update rule?